# How to define a new quantifier?

Tags: macros, symbols, math-operators, logic

I would like to define new quantifier-like symbols from letters other than A and E.

The command `\reflectbox{\mathsf{#1}}` achieves this to some extent, except `\mathsf` makes the text bolder than it should. (The same happens with `\textsf`.)

Compare, for example the thickness of `\reflectbox{\mathsf{E}}` and `\exists`.

What other approach can I take?

**OP edit:**

I am particularly interested in having the output of `\reflectbox{\mathsf{Q}}`, but with the thickness of `\exists`.
If possible, though, I am interested in a general approach to this rather than in one that only works for Q.

Comment: Hello. You should give at least one visual example of what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @projetmbc. See my edit above.

Comment: note that as far as TeX is concerned forall and exists are unrelated to A and E, they are not made by rotating, they are simply characters in the font that have some similarity to a rotated letter, but same relationship as say 6 and 9. This means that you can't apply the same methods used for forall to a rotated Q unless you design a new font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a thin sans serif font, which is available in the ClearSans font face. The strokes are not rounded, so it is better to redefine also the standard quantifiers. In the picture I show the comparison.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\newcommand{\clearthin}{\usefont{\encodingdefault}{ClearSans-TLF}{thin}{n}}
\newcommand{\definequantifier}[3]{%1 = command, #2 = h or v, #3 = letter
  \if #2h%
    \DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\text{\clearthin#3}}}%
  \else
    \DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\text{\clearthin#3}}}}%
  \fi
}

% for the comparison
\let\oriexists\exists
\let\oriforall\forall
%%%

\definequantifier{\exists}{h}{E}
\definequantifier{\forall}{v}{A}
\definequantifier{\qfoo}{h}{Q}



\begin{document}

$\oriexists x\oriforall y$

$\exists x\forall y\qfoo z$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @egreg. Your solution seems perfect, but for some reason `\clearthin` doesn't work either outside or `\definequantifier`. Even when I just use your exact MWE, `\clearthin` returns the regular font type.

Comment: @lfba You should ensure to have the `ClearSans` package installed. What TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by `ClearSans` package, @egreg? Is there a LaTeX package called like that? I have downloaded and installed the `ClearSans` fonts, and then I have rebooted my computer. I am using PdfLaTeX as compiler (with TeXstudio as environment).

Comment: @lfba Are you on MiKTeX?

Comment: Thanks @egreg, it seems that properly switching from TeXLive to MiKTeX solved the issue. But it is possible that it was only the fact that I installed the fonts in the proper folder.